# selenium python: my code returns an error

Tags: python, selenium, automated-tests

I can't figure this out. I'm looking for a button element. My program keeps hanging on:

```
button_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("""//input[@onclick=\'return displayURLWithFocus(\'preview.aspx\?id=1692003076\');\'""")
```

I get this error:

```
    SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': 
The string '//input[@onclick='return displayURLWithFocus('preview.aspx\?id=1692003076');'' 
is not a valid XPath expression.
```

Something must be wrong with the quotes?

Comment: shouldn't `preview.aspx\?` be `preview.aspx/?` and you seem to be missing the last `]` to close the expression

Answer (score 0):

maybe

```
button_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("""//input[@onclick=\'return displayURLWithFocus(\'preview.aspx/?id=1692003076\');\']""")
```

Comment: Nope, I got this error: '//input[@onclick='return displayURLWithFocus('preview.aspx/?id=1692003076');']' is not a valid XPath expression.

Comment: BTW, this is the html: onclick="return displayURLWithFocus('preview.aspx?id=1692003076');"

Comment: then it may be a limitation of Selenium. It doesn't support the full XPath syntax, and maybe you need to add a label or some other way to look up this element

Answer (score 0):

I got it:

```
button_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("""//input[@onclick="return displayURLWithFocus(\'preview.aspx?id=1692003076\');"]""")
```